# Enabling write permissions Ubuntu Server in var/www/image directory

Tags: php, linux, apache, ubuntu

I'm trying to get my php test upload script to work and was wondering what the command would be to allow files to be uploaded in ubuntu server in the var/www/image directory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
cd /var/www/image
```

For file like image you don't need execution permission :

```
sudo chmod 664 *
```

If you have directories inside image and you want to apply permission :

```
sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 "{}" \;
```

This will recursively search your directory and chmod 755 all directories only.

Similarly, the following will chmod all files only (and ignore the directories):

```
sudo find . -type f -exec chmod 644 "{}" \;
```

File name with space case (thanks to Nicklas B)

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 644
```

Comment: This will not work so well for filenames with spaces, whereas `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 644` should work in every case.

Comment: Ok thanks for the precision! I prefer not use spaces in filenames, I've never seen this problem.

Comment: @NiklasB. Or you can just quote the filename in `-exec` (as I've just edited)

Comment: @Oli: Yeah, that works, too. I'm mostly using `xargs`, just because I'm too lazy to remember the weird `-exec` syntax.

Comment: @NiklasB. I'm exactly the same way with trying to remember how xargs handles lines/spaces/etc with the various print methods.

Comment: @alain.janinm  If i want the folders and the images write by web server user only and images reads by every one your answer will work ?

Answer (score 13):

What username will be uploading the files?  Usually on Ubuntu the Apache web server username is **www-data**.  You can check for sure by finding the web server process in a process list command and seeing which username under which it is running.

`ps aux | grep apache` or `ps aux | grep httpd` should give you that answer.

Then you will usually want to make that Apache username the owner of the directory and all files and directories within it:

```
cd /var/www/image
# recursively (all subdirs & files) set owner to www-data for current directory
chown -R www-data .
```

Ordinarily, the above should be enough, but if for some reason the directory, files or subdirectories do not have write permission for the owner username, that's easily fixed by changing the permissions to add that write access, like this:

```
cd /var/www/image
# recursively add "w"rite permissions for the "u"ser (owner) to current directory
chmod -R u+w .
```

Answer (score 1):

Change edit group to www-data

chown -R (owner):www-data (folder)

And folder permission to 775

Answer (score 0):

`cd /var/www`

`sudo chmod 775 image`

You'll be prompted to enter the admin password - do so, and hit [return].

Answer (score -1):

Change edit group may solve most of the problems of permissions.

Changing do www-data and set permission to 775.