# PHP: Upload a file to a local ubuntu server

Tags: php, ubuntu, file-upload, chmod

I have been working on a simple form that upload an Excel file to a server and manipulates it, then gives me the option to download it.

On my WAMP server it works perfectly!

After uploading it to the Local Ubuntu server i get this error on the "Network" after sending it to the file that handles it:

```
Request URL:http://10.0.0.66/PHPExcel/main.php
Request Method:POST
Status Code:500 Internal Server Error
Remote Address:10.0.0.66:80
Response Headers
view source
Connection:close
Content-Length:1
Content-Type:text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date:Wed, 02 Mar 2016 16:51:42 GMT
Server:Apache/2.4.12 (Ubuntu)
Request Headers
view source
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Cache-Control:max-age=0
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:10621
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryTlu6BO9uHeeHBF5X
Cookie:ci_session=1ce8fcaf8b36c7a2cf254077b1682edca9e771e3
Host:10.0.0.66
Origin:http://10.0.0.66
Referer:http://10.0.0.66/PHPExcel/
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36
Request Payload
------WebKitFormBoundaryTlu6BO9uHeeHBF5X
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="0103.xlsx"
Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet


------WebKitFormBoundaryTlu6BO9uHeeHBF5X
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="MOS"

android
------WebKitFormBoundaryTlu6BO9uHeeHBF5X--
```

What can be the problem?

I thought maybe it's because there aren't permissions to upload the files so I found this post: 
[Enabling write permissions Ubuntu Server in var/www/image directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9181254/enabling-write-permissions-ubuntu-server-in-var-www-image-directory)

and used:

```
root@server:/var/www/html# sudo chmod 664 *
root@server:/var/www/html# sudo find . -type d -exec chmod 755 "{}" \;
```

Is there a different way to upload a file to a Linux server than a local WAMP server?

Comment: are there any errors in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`?

Comment: `PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(upload/56d71e3a0b1447.40123190.xlsx): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/html/PHPExcel/main.php on line 46, referer: http://10.0.0.94/PHPExcel/`

I have there: `if ($file_size > 0) {
    
    $file_name_new = uniqid('', true) . '.' . $file_ext;
    $destination = "upload/$file_name_new";
    
    move_uploaded_file($file_tmp, $destination);

   }`

Comment: Very Simple bro just give permission to upload folder 777 and that's all!!

Comment: @IndrasinhBihola worked!

Comment: But cant that be bad from a security point of view?

Comment: I am running my code and don't get the final result right. 
I should get a new excel file and this is the error I get:

Comment: `PHP Warning:  unlink(keywords.xlsx): Permission denied in /var/www/html/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php on line 229, referer: http://10.0.0.66/PHPExcel/

unlink(keywords.xlsx): Permission denied in /var/www/html/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php on line 229, referer: http://10.0.0.66/PHPExcel/
unlink(keywords.xlsx): Permission denied in /var/www/html/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/Writer/Excel2007.php on line 229, referer: http://10.0.0.66/PHPExcel/`

Comment: Yeah It's bad but you can try 755 instead of 777. It seems like you don't have permission to remove keywords.xlsx. Everytime you create a new file you need to change it's permission to 644. I think that would solve your problem.

Comment: Tried with 755 and it didn't work. What do you mean by "Everytime you create a new file you need to change it's permission to 644"? 
with the PHP command of CHMOD? when changing the CHMOD within the PHP does it apply the change permanently? nothing there mentions this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.chmod.php

Answer (score 0):

For the specific folder where uploads land, ensure you have permission as 777, as suggested by Indrasinh

Comment: That's what I did, everything works now. 
But the question is... is this the right+secure way to do it? 
I opened a new post for that: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35769507/php-and-chmod-permissions-uploading-a-file-to-my-server-and-saving-a-new-one-wi